# restar fecha con moment y compararla en query

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola disculpen me inico en esto tengo un query en donde dada la fecha actual me traiga todos los usuarios que fueron creados en las ultimas 48 horas, tengo este codigo pero no se honestamente en que falla:

```
 var hoy=(moment(Date.now()).subtract(2, 'd')).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");;



    var ListarUsuariosMaxDate =
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            var lista = UserSos.find(
                { 
                    "createdAt" : { 
                        "$gt" : hoy
                    }
                }
            , (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
                    if (!err) {

                        return registrosEncontrados

                    }
                }
            )
            resolve(lista);

        })
```

Disculpen los errores si son muy evidentes...el fomrato de la variable hoy es 2020-05-13T18:25:08 y en BD 2019-07-04T17:00:15.239Z, gracias nuevamente...

Comment: Puede ser el formato de fecha este mal, puedes mostrar un ejemplo de como estas guardando el formato de fecha en tu base de datos?

Comment: gracias ya modifique la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moment` puede devolverte un tipo `date`. Así que remplaza `format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")`
por `toDate()`

```
var hoy=(moment(Date.now()).subtract(2, 'd')).toDate();
```

Y debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias @Angel siempre tan certero...